# Using XMPP Client inside docker container

Tags: docker, xmpp, node-xmpp

I am not able to use xmpp client inside a docker container. I used this code it is working very well on my machine but not in a docker container.

```
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp-client');
var client = new xmpp.Client({
                jid:  'xxxx@gcm.googleapis.com',
                password: 'xyz',
                port: 5235,
                host: 'fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com',
                reconnect : true,
                legacySSL: true,
                preferredSaslMechanism : 'PLAIN'
        });
client.on('online', function() {
                console.log('fcm online');
});
client.on('close', function() {
                console.log('fcm close');
});
client.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
                console.log('fcm stanza');
});
client.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e);
});
```

Does anyone know what might be going on? I checked firewall , I can connect through ports 5222,5223, 5269,5298 from inside the container using netcat.

Comment: Have you tried launching docker with `--net=host` option? It looks like fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com has no connectivity using network interfaces inside docker.

Comment: tried `telnet fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com 5235`, there was no problem connecting.

Comment: tried also with `--net=host` same result.